# Spinner JSON Loading

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I did have a look at  [spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), but in the program that I am working on the data on the spinner is loaded from an API ... Being new, I sort of don't have any idea on loading the JSONObjects onto the spinner. Help please.

The API reply is sort of like this :

```
{"status":"","data":{"1":"scorpio"},"message":""}
```

Where I would have to display the value "Scorpio" the spinner and at the backend assign the value "1" while passing the form. Help please.

Comment: Have you solved your problem.

Comment: i actually made use of an ordinary spinner.

Comment: You asked how to load JSON data in spinner that only i gave as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in the following way

> {"data":[{"1":"scorpio"},{"2":"BMW"},{"3":"Scoda"}]}

then you retrieve and show that in the spinner as follows:-

```
String[] id,name;

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(your data);
JSONObject jdata = jObject.getJSONArray("data");

id = new String[jdata.length()];
name = new String[jdata.length()];

Iterator<?> keys = jSEngineers.keys();

for(int i=0;i<jdata.length();i++){
id[i] = (String) keys.next();
name[i] = (String) jSEngineers.getString(id[i]);
}
```

Now you can get those values into the specified arrays.Now you can assign  required one to Spinner.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name);
spinnerName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now you can get selected spinner item as follows

```
spinnerName.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

with this you will get the position  of the item.with the help of that you can retrieve your required id that is for your background purpose.As follows..

```
Log.i("Item id is",id[spinnerName.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your JSON array into array and simple assign to spinners in loop:

```
//json array
{"Employee":[{"Id":73,"Name":"Bård Pedersen","Email":"bp@spillbasen.com","Mobile":"9004422"}]}

ArrayList<String> TAG_ID = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TAG_NAME = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TAG_EMAIL = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = new ArrayList<String>();

  // Getting Array of Employee
        employee = json.getJSONArray("Employee");

        // looping through All Employee
        for (int i = 0; i < employee.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = employee.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            id = c.getString("Id");
            name = c.getString("Name");
            email = c.getString("Email");
            mobile = c.getString("Mobile");

            // adding all get values into array
            if (name != "null" && mobile != "null") {
                TAG_NAME.add(name);
                TAG_ID.add(id);
                TAG_EMAIL.add(email);
                TAG_PHONE_MOBILE.add(mobile);
                close.add(R.drawable.close);
            }
```